# Randomizing order of IEnumerator

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have an IEnumerator which has collection of some pictures(Enumarator of PictureCollection object). I want this to appear in random order, means the pictures can appear at random index. Is there any inbuilt C# method to do that or any workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to shuffle the elements of an IEnumerable in a random way.

```
Random rand = new Random();
var models = garage.OrderBy(c => rand.Next()).Select(c => c.Model).ToList();
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180038/randomly-shuffle-a-list).

Comment: I don't think the select is required.

Comment: Excellent that's what I required. Although I was talking about IEnumerator, not IEnumerable, but I am using a List instead of IEnumerator anyways now. Thanks and yeah I didn't require Select :-)